# regex for anything after expression is optional but cannot contain specific characters (what am I doing wrong)?

Tags: regex, google-analytics, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

Here is what I have so far:

```
./((phraseone|second-phrase|third|fourth)\s*?[^(a-zA-Z\w\d\-\_\.)+])
```

Okay... What I'm attempting to do:

find any of the for words , which are preceeded by a slash.
(hence the "./"  )
Then find any of the four phrases
what follows those phrases should
 - NOT be a letter upper or lower case
 - NOT be a number
 - NOT be a word (is that redundant?)
 - NO "-" "_" or "." allowed to follow the phrase

EX:
FOUND would = true on

```
/phraseone?hello=yes
/phraseone
/phraseone&mydog=skip
```

BUT 
FOUND would = false on

```
/phraseonemore
/phraseone-more
etc
```

Thank you in advance

PS is

```
./
```

the proper way to search for a phase and it MUST HAVE the slash preceding one of the four phrases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead like this:

```
./(phraseone|second-phrase|third|fourth)(?![-\w.])
```

**PS:** `\w` is equivalent of `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: AWESOME! THANK YOU!
ps would this do the same?

(?![a-zA-Z\d\-\_\.])

once I started typing in the tags I saw this phrase negative lookahead... thats what I needed - isn't it?
QUESTION: why was this not working: [^(a-zA-Z.....)]? Was it that my brackets were in the wrong order?

Comment: That is not working because inside character class you can only use individual characters. You can use group of characters inside character class.

Comment: Thank you THANK YOU -- .. I must wait 18 seconds to approve this answer

Comment: Thanks for explaining it! so Character Class = single character only? ... No wait -- I can use multiple characters but I must name them individually. GOT IT! Thanks again anubhava

Comment: You're welcome, glad it helped. [See this nice reference on character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: thank you again for the reference to character class -- this helps a lot